# Can't login into development copy of Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I'd like to create a local copy on my Windows 8 machine to further develop existing extensions and test upcoming updates of a Typo3 6.1.7 installation. I tared everything up including the MySQL DB dump, extracted it into a fresh install of XAMPP and imported the database. After adjusting the DB and OpenSSL settings in the LocalConfiguration.php I tried to login with my password, but I get a message stating my credentials must be wrong.

The LoginSecurity on BE is configured with RSA, and the InstallTool states that my OpenSSL config is running correct. Then why can't I login? What did I miss?

Comment: TYPO3 6.2 LTS seems to support Mysql 5.6

Comment: I know, thats why I want a working copy, to further develop our own extensions and testing them on 6.2 LTS and all upcoming patches and other extension updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching what could be wrong I looked at the requirements for Typo3 6.1.x, and it clearly states that it supports MySQL 5.5.x. Sure enough, the freshly installed XAMPP uses MySQL 5.6. I removed it, installed the other current XAMPP package with MySQL 5.5 and now it works.