# Setup TYPO3 for development on Windows (Apache + OpenSSL)

Tags: windows, openssl, typo3, backend

Setting up TYPO3 on Windows using an Apache server poses some problems I've noticed. Solutions are sporadic and/or incomplete in many instances.

There are [the requirements](http://typo3.org/typo3-cms/overview/requirements/), not being able to [connect to the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938313/cannot-connect-to-typo3-v6-2-1-backend-on-windows-7), [openssl not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140956/xampp-3-2-1-and-typo3-6-2-openssl-not-working/24346938) and a [few more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244417/cant-login-into-development-copy-of-typo3).

So, how to setup TYPO3 on a Windows machine for development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was made with:

- [Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/business/default.aspx)
- [Ampps](http://ampps.com/) (Apache/MySQL)
- [GraphicMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org)

## **Setting up Typo3 on a Windows machine using a local server**

### **Apache & MySQL**

Make sure you have a local server with Apache and MySQL, such as [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), [Ampps](http://www.ampps.com/) or another.

Settings this up we'll call the "project" we're going to start: typotest

- Create a folder in the "www" or "wwwroot" of your Apache server called "typotest"
- Create a virtual domain for your project, in Ampps go to localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage (Make sure the server is up and running first!), called "typotest". This will make your project accessible through http:// typotest/ (remove space)
- On your machine, go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` and open the "hosts" file in the folder with administrator. Add a record at the bottom: `127.0.0.1    typotest`. Save it and make sure it's there.
- Open the Apache `httpd.conf` file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\apache\conf
- Make sure the following lines are **not** commented in the file (remove `#`)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

- At the bottom of the file, add the following code

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

- Save the file
- Open the `php.ini` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php` and make sure the following lines aren't commented (remove ';')

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
//edit these lines to be the same
post_max_size = 32M
max_execution_time = 240
```

We're done with Apache.

### **OpenSSL**

Go to [here](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html), or if the link is still active, straight [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Download the most recent 32-bit release of OpenSSL for Windows. I used 2 installations, not sure which one was the correct one.

- Visual C++ 2008 Redistrubutable 1.7MB installer (Description: Having problems with error messages when trying to run OpenSSL? This will likely fix the problem. Only works with Windows 2000 and later. Although there is a "newer version" of this installer, this is the correct version to install.)
- Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1j (Description: Installs Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1j (Recommended for software developers by the creators of OpenSSL). Note that this is a default build of OpenSSL and is subject to local and state laws. More information can be found in the legal agreement of the installation.)

That should take care of having OpenSSL installed on your Windows machine.

### **Additional software**

By default, Typo3 cannot handle images out of the box. For it to be able to handle these you need to install [GraphicMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/index.html) and a setting needs to be modified. The setting we'll get to later during the configuration of Typo3 itself.

The software you'll need is [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/), download the latest version of GraphicMagick. Get the version that's right for your system (and preferably corresponds to your server). You have the choice between 32/64bit, obviously, but also Q8 and Q16, these correspond to image quality (higher is better).

### **Windows**

To setup Windows to have globally usable variables we need to add them to the system settings. I again used two methods and it might be a question of either/or.

- Go to "System" (Windows key + Pause/Break key) (Control Panel/System)
- Select on the left: "Advanced system settings"
- Go to tab: "advanced"
- Hit button: "Environment variables..."
- Click "New..." to add a new variable
- Name this new variable: "OPENSSL_CONF"
- Remember, I used Ampps, so the Variable Value for me is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\apache\conf\openssl.cnf` -> Press "OK"
- Scroll down in the variables list and select variable: "Path"
- Click "Edit..."
- Behind the existing variable add: `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\apache\bin` (including the semicolon at the front!!!)
- Save it

**Reboot Windows at this time**

### **PHPMyAdmin**

Open PHPMyAdmin and create a new database named "typotest". Also create a user for this database with the same name and password. (This is for convenience's sake of this setup, these 3 are ideally different and this practice should **never** happen on a production environment!)

### **Typo3 Installation**

Download Typo3, I've used v6.2.6. Extract it to the earlier created folder in the "www" or "wwwroot" folder of your local server. Next:

- Create a file in the "/www/typotest" or "/wwwroot/typotest" called "FIRST_INSTALL", no extension for this file.
- Now start the installation by going to `typotest/typo3/install` in a browser.
- Follow the 5 steps of the installation, entering values created above where necessary
- **Stop** before you log into the backend!
- Open the file `/www/typotest/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` in an editor
- Search for the following variables and edit to settings below:

```
'loginSecurityLevel' => 'normal'
'devIPmask' => '*'
'displayErrors' => 2
```

- Now refresh the login page and login.
- In the left menu go to "Install" and select the "Unlock the Install Tool" button
- Enter password and continue
- Go to "All configuration"
- Select "Toggle all" below
- Search for "rsa"
- Where it says: "[BE][loginSecurityLevel] = rsa" change "rsa" to "normal" in the inputfield below.
- Modify [FE][activateContentAdapter] = 1 //This enables the viewing of images [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265924/typo3-distribution-png-issue-when-posting-images)
- Modify [GFX][im_path] to the path of your GraphicMagick installation (e.g.: C:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick\ )
- Modify [GFX][im_path_lzw] to the path of your GraphicMagick installation (e.g.: C:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick\ )
- Modify [GFX][im_version_5] to "gm" (short for GraphicMagick)

  Choose "Write configuration" at the bottom of the page. This saves this setting from becoming reset to default "rsa" for BackEnd ([BE]) login. (Make sure to change this back when going to production!)

---

This might not help everyone out there but it's all the stuff I had to change to get Typo3 to work and it might help a few future souls that have the same or similar troubles.